# What is a good tutorial / reference for developing apps using Ruby on Rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm specifically looking for 'Getting Started' or 'Cookbook' that deals with RoR 2.3.5. It's primarily because my webhost supports RoR 2.3.5 and not the latest and greatest - 3.0 Pointers would be appreciated to docs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

You can switch between Rails 3 and Rails 2.3 on the right.

Comment: sorry but I was trying to "uncheck" my +1 since I added a different answer. But I didn't realize "downvoting" is different "unchecking". Tried to fix it but SO won't let me change it :(

Comment: Mistakes happen :)  However, why make an own answer out of the same link for recommending Rails 3 instead of adding a comment here? The author seems to be aware of Rails 3 and explicitly asked for Rails 2.3. And sure, Heroku is great and he would have found out in the Tutorial... . I do not see the point in adding another answer despite the +25 points on acceptance ;)

Comment: I guess the way I see it comments are usually "in addition" type of info. But I felt my answer was different enough to be put on it's own. If you want to edit your answer to include the info about Heroku along with encouragement to start with rails 3 over rails 2 I'd be happy to delete my answer and upvote yours!

Comment: Cool. thanks for pointing out switching between rails 2 and 3 :)

Comment: If you head for Rails 3 here is another link: http://rails-nutshell.labs.oreilly.com/index.html.

Answer (score 4):

As @Markus said [railstutorial.org](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) is the best resource for getting started with rails (2 and 3).

HOWEVER, I highly recommend starting with Rails 3. It's a big change going from 2 to 3 and might as well start with the best that's currently out there.

Also, the fact that your current webhost supports rails 2 shouldn't be an issue since you can host small sites on [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) for free. And what do ya know, railstutorial.org will teach you how to use Heroku as well.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I will definitely consider using Rails 3 instead of 2. Don't want to learn concepts that need to be reworked/thrown away if thats the case.

Comment: I don't even use a webhost these days. All of my Rails apps (including the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://railstutorial.org/) site itself) run on [Heroku](http://heroku.com). I second the recommendation to start with the Rails 3 version of the book; I published the Rails 2 version of the book mainly for people who needed to support legacy applications.

Answer (score 2):

www.railscasts.com

you can find any kind of tutuorial/screencast here.

www.peepcode.com. Not free, but not expensive either. Very good tutorials about rails 2

Comment: I have learned more than half of my Rails skills through Railscasts.com. Ryan Bytes is amazing!

Comment: Railscasts (and Asciicasts) are possibly the best source on Rails, however, they are not the ideal way to start with Rails as Ryan does not teach basic concepts in a connected manner.